# Bixolon SPP-R200 thermal printer - error light blinks when it detects black marker

Tags: printer

I have 2 Bixolon SPP-R200 thermal printers. I've been working on an Android app that prints via bluetooth. However, for one of the printers, every time it hits the black marker the printer stops and the red light flashes.

Android app aside, this happens even if I press the feed button and the sensor detects the black marker. It even happens during the test print - I have to open the case, pull the paper past the marker and close it for the print to continue. I have to repeat this process until the test print is complete. This happens in Label Mode or Receipt Mode.

The strange thing with this model is that I can't get it to auto-calibrate - instead of asking me what I want to do, it goes straight into test print mode.

I was able to auto-calibrate the second printer. However, now this printer is behaving the same way. That is, whenever the sensor detects the black marker, the printer stops and the red light starts blinking.

I should mention that the paper in the device (with the black marker) has been used for years to print tickets.

Am I missing something or have these two devices decided to die at the same time?

Comment: Hi, I hope you have solve this problem. Care to share how you solved it? I face this problem now and stuck.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the devices anymore and I'm having trouble remembering what the solution was exactly. But I have a feeling that it was something to do with the bytes being sent are mis-aligned somehow

Comment: Looking through my code/PRs looks like there could have been a number of factors. For one thing, closing an Activity was killing long running processes (when data was being sent). So I wrote some code to perform background processing using RxJava

Comment: Also I added auto-connect/re-connect code. Looks like there were times when bluetooth connection would be severed (for one reason or other)

Comment: Also I remember reducing the size of the buffer helped. In my notes I had this, "Noticed error messages surrounding tx buffer size
Converted printBitmap() to use small buffer"

Comment: Also, this comment might be helpful - "FF does work in Standard Mode"

Comment: Also this - "Ditched Page Mode. It seems that what you're supposed to do is use Label Mode with Standard Mode. The user then feeds to the next tear line by pressing the feed button on the printer
Added printer_mode user setting. User can force Label Mode or Receipt Mode with each print"

Comment: Sorry I haven't been more helpful. I know from experience just how frustrating the documentation is for this thing!